# Using different types of Id in entity, depending of database

Tags: c#, database, entity

I have a C# .NET 7 library MyLib with domain services and entity like

```
class User
{
   string Name
   string Address
   ...
}
```

And I have some sub-libraries like MyLib.EfCore, MyLib.RavenDb, MyLib.LiteDb, etc., that implements Repository and UoW.

So, in application, in IServiceCollection setup main library and database one are chained like .UseMyLib().WithRavenDb() for example.

The problem is in entity Id type.

- RavenDb needs string Id,
- LiteDb - it's own ObjectId (yes, it can work with int, Guid, but let's use ObjectId for complexity),
- EfCore - int/guid and other (see previous point)

Adding different Id types to User class (StringId + GuidId + ObjectIdId) looks very ugly.

I think about using in User class strong-typed Id, with separate implementations in each database library - in RavenDb with internal storage of this strong-typed Id as string, in EfC - as Guid, in LiteDb - as ObjectId. But I have no idea how to make it - and even if it is possible.

Does anyone have an ideas?

Comment: Idea? I am close to call it trying to solve a problem you do not have. If you think the fields are your problem - the smallest common denominator is brutally low. if you want to actually USE the database to any relevant higher level, this approach is a dead end. It is THE anti pattern for anythiung that is not on a hello world level. Heck, EfCore itself is hard to handle for compelx stuff, but you can there at least offload to SP's and manually write proper db setup. .See that on your cv. you talk about it not disgusted - I recommend you to the competition.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you ask for an idea, here is the ONLY way that works outside of making a totally bad approach worse by overengineering something on top.

Strings. Strings work everywhere. You decided you want the smallest common denominator, live with it.

UOW wrappers around EfCore already are a "thanks, for the the competition" level of idea - EfCore IS a unit of work repository. You just create a REALLY BAD repository around it - because I have yet to see a repository that is not just a facade and breaks internally every rule ever done (like, you can not do joins in repositories except outside od them, giving up any join, link, include etc. that EfCore offers). You give up - for SqlServer - any higher feature that may be critical an requires manual programming on the db side. SP#s for complex analysis, filtered indices, column store indices. Lowest common denominator - everything is a string.